# Bang blue cards question

Tags: bang

I know how many cards you have to end with in your turn I was wondering if the blue cards that you played like mustang or scope counts as part of your hand

Answer (score 3):

The number of cards in your hand equals the number of lives (bullets) you have left.

Cards played do not count as being in your hand. So you can have as much blue cards on the table as you like.